# php, mysql, how to compare two strings?

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables in 2 different databases:
`database1.table1` that looks like:

```
id | word1
1    test1
2    test2
3    test3
```

and `database2.table2` that looks like:

```
price | word2
10      test1
15      test2
30      test3
```

how can i compare `word1` and `word2` to see if the keys from `word2` are found in `word1` in either a mysql join or php

any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to check if all "keys" from `word1` are in `word2` or get the intersection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.word1, t2.price
  FROM database1.table1 t1 
  JOIN database2.table2 t2 
    ON t1.word1 = t2.word2;
```

Comment: Run the query and the result set will contain what you want. Do you know how to execute mysql queries in PHP?

Comment: yes, lets say `$result1 = mysql_fetch_array(query from table1)` and `$result2 = mysql_fetch_array(query from table2)`. `$result1` will have both `id` and `word1` and `$result2` will have both `price` and `word2`. how do i compare `$result1['word1'] and $result2['word2']` and still get all results

Comment: Why don't you just use the query in my answer? Your `$result` array will contain `id`, `word` and `price` without any post-processing needed. You did ask for either a mysql or php solution...

Comment: They are aliases for the tables, so instead of writing `database1.table1` all the time, you can simply call `t1`. Try to do `var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($the_query_here));` to see what the data looks like.

Comment: but why you place them in the beginning: `SELECT t1.id, t1.word1, t2.price`, they were not beeing alised until after the `FROM`

Comment: `t1.id` means that I'm getting the id from the table aliased as `t1`. The alias is declared later on but it doesn't matter. So `t2.price` means "the column `price`, from the table `database2.table2` which is aliased as `t2`". You should read on some basic SQL functions to have a better understanding of how it works. It will help you in your applications!